# Adding a multiple columns to a dataframe with apply and regexpr

Tags: r, regex

I have a data.frame with 2 columns. One of these column is used to store the colors of each product (in rows). I also have a list of colors
See example below :

```
df <- data.frame(Product = c("a","b","c"), 
           Color = c("black-white-silver-red","black-white-red","black-white"))
colorNames <- list('black','red','silver')
```

I am trying to add new columns to the data.frame based on thelist of color. The purpose of the column would be to return 0 or 1 depending whether the color is in the product. Ideally the output would look like this:

```
    Product                  Color   black   red   silver    
1        a black-white-silver-red        1     1        1
2        b        black-white-red        1     1        0
3        c            black-white        1     0        0
```

I have tried to use the regexpr function combined with lapply.
The following code doesn't work:

```
lapply(colorsNames, function(color){
  transform(df, df[[color]] = as.integer(regexpr(color,df$Color)>0) )
 })
```

However, this one works fine but I am not able to apply it to a vector of color:

```
transform(df, black = as.integer(regexpr('black',df$Color)>0) )
```

I would really appreciate if soemone knew how to apply the last code to a vector of colors.
Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Here a quick solution using `stringi` package. Currently returns counts that might be binarized. There are certainly more clever ways to achieve this, but I think as an initial approach this is what you need.

If your data set is really large I would recommend to use `data.table` instead of `data.frame`. Furthermore, you might consider using `text2vec` package (or other similar packages) to create your counts by considering your Color as a document and apply text mining on this column. However, I guess, that in your case, this would be overshoot. Otherwise, please let me know and I can provide an alternative solution.

```
check_occurrence <- function(df, check_col, patterns) {
 occurrence <-  sapply(patterns, function(x) {
    stri_count_regex(df[,check_col], x) #maybe stri_count_fixed suffices (would be faster)
  })
 colnames(occurrence) <- patterns
 cbind(df, occurrence)  
}

check_occurrence(df = df, check_col = 2, patterns = colorNames)
#   Product                  Color black red silver
# 1       a black-white-silver-red     1   1      1
# 2       b        black-white-red     1   1      0
# 3       c            black-white     1   0      0

#to binarize results do something like
#df[df > 1] <- 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Manuel.
In reality I have a list that contains 4 list of 8 data.frame each.
I have more than 1700 different colors in total. 

Please tell me if you need more details

Comment: You might check how long it takes to process one of the data.frames with my approach before we go further. Maybe its still fast enough. If it takes too long, simply stop the process. If you are not sure how to apply my approach to your data, please update your data sample to show how the structure of your real data looks like, so I can update my answer to fit your data.

Comment: Your solution seems to work perfectly. The only thing is that it will return the number of occurrence while I am looking for a dummy variable.

Comment: Does the command `df[df > 1] <- 1` which I have inserted as comment in my code not turn the data into what you want? Could you specify again what you mean by dummy variable, I can certainly help you to format the output as you need it.

Comment: I didn't see the command, sorry :) It works on this example because there is only checking columns that have numeric variables. I did not show it in my example but my data.frame has many different columns with numeric value (not only the checking columns)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Manuel, here is my final code (in case some people have kind of the same issue).

```
    check.colorsOccurrence <- function(list,colorsList){

  if(is.data.frame(list)){  checkedColors <- sapply(colorsList, function(color){
       ifelse(regexpr(color, list$Color) < 0,0,1)
    })
    colnames(checkedColors) <- colorsList
cbind(list,checkedColors)
 }
    else  lapply(list, function(listElmt){
    if(!is.data.frame(listElmt)) check.colorsOccurrence(listElmt, colorsList)
    else {  checkedColors <- sapply(colorsList, function(color){
  ifelse(regexpr(color, listElmt$Color) < 0,0,1)
  })
  colnames(checkedColors) <- colorsList
  cbind(listElmt,checkedColors)
   }
 })
}
```